# Retrieving data from an abstract class

Tags: java, class, ycsb

I am having difficulty accessing some data. I am using [YCSB](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/) to talk to a number of different databases, such as Cassandra and MongoDB.

The only class I can really modify is my "Workload" class, which is doing some insertions and reads. The method I am using to read from the database is in the class:

```
public void doRead(DB db)
{
    String keyname = buildKeyName(keynum);
    System.out.println(keyname);
    HashSet<String> fields = null;

    if (!readallfields)
    {
        // read a random field
        String fieldname = "field" + fieldchooser.nextString();
        fields = new HashSet<String>();
        fields.add(fieldname);
    }

db.read(table,keyname,fields,new HashMap<String,ByteIterator>());
}
```

I tried to modify the code so I could read the contents of the hashmap. I removed the db.read line and replaced it with

```
HashMap<String, ByteIterator> kv_hashmap = new HashMap<String, ByteIterator>();
db.read(table, keyname, fields, kv_hashmap);
```

Then tried to read from kv_hashmap:

```
System.out.println(kv_hashmap.get(fields));
```

**BUT** db.read returns only an int. DB is a public abstract class which I would rather not modify and its purpose is to talk to a variety of databases:

This is what db.read calls:

```
public abstract int read(String table, String key, Set<String> fields, HashMap<String,ByteIterator> result);
```

Which returns, to quote from the javadoc:

> Zero on success, a non-zero error code on error or "not found".

I need to read the values from kv_hashmap. I don't understand why I can't access its values.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Please show in code what you are trying to accomplish and why it's not working.

Comment: What should an implementation of the read-Method do? does it put all keys with fields of the table in the given hashMap? and after the call of read you want to acces the informations via the hashmap, is that your purpose?

Comment: Yes, the read should store the field data in the hashmap. I wish to access that info via the hashmap, as you stated. Instead db.read() returns an int

Comment: what output does System.out.println(kv_hashmap.get(fields)); give you?  Does the read method populate the map? Some APIs return a boolean/int to indicate the result of an operation, but additionally populate a collection of some sort with the actual details - this could be the case here

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the implementation of the DB class and the javadoc additionally says:

```
 @param result A HashMap of field/value pairs for the result
```

But, I then also looked at `BasicDB` which extends `DB` - and its body simply prints out the fields passed in.

What I suggest you do is print the actual concrete class of `DB` being passed into your method and see what that class is actually doing inside the `read` method, something like:

```
System.out.println(Test.class.getName());
```

Then take a look at the `read` method of whatever class is shown - if its not populating the `result` HashMap (as with the `BasicDB` implementation) then there wont be anything for you to read